Do oscillator strengths matter when matching theoretical and experimental outcomes?
I use ORCA to do TD-DFT studies. The experimental maximum absorption is esteemed to 445.0nm . Benchmark computations were conducted and this is the exemplatory (part of) the output:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         ABSORPTION SPECTRUM VIA TRANSITION ELECTRIC DIPOLE MOMENTS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
State   Energy    Wavelength  fosc         T2        TX        TY        TZ  
        (cm-1)      (nm)                 (au**2)    (au)      (au)      (au) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   19363.4    516.4   0.001445679   0.02458   0.14938   0.02557   0.04012
   2   19933.3    501.7   0.000059450   0.00098  -0.02560  -0.00489   0.01740
   3   21112.6    473.7   0.216020030   3.36843   1.81690   0.17217   0.19409
   4   21402.1    467.2   0.003124961   0.04807   0.19691   0.04527   0.08512
   5   21457.9    466.0   0.010176631   0.15613  -0.31453  -0.18875  -0.14687
   6   22215.9    450.1   0.034572610   0.51232   0.19985  -0.09498  -0.68071
   7   22453.4    445.4   0.038416867   0.56327  -0.22576   0.69902  -0.15386
   8   24113.1    414.7   0.001205412   0.01646  -0.12635   0.00308  -0.02198
   9   25908.9    386.0   0.001447762   0.01840  -0.03761  -0.08221  -0.10111
  10   25959.1    385.2   0.001181198   0.01498  -0.01637  -0.09627   0.07379
  11   27693.0    361.1   0.003253266   0.03867   0.16248  -0.09039  -0.06406
  12   27756.8    360.3   0.001378465   0.01635  -0.03673   0.06090  -0.10626
  13   27886.6    358.6   0.000132151   0.00156   0.00314   0.02551   0.02999
  14   28082.6    356.1   0.000100820   0.00118  -0.00050   0.02214  -0.02630
  15   28270.3    353.7   0.000273816   0.00319  -0.05566  -0.00872   0.00378
  16   28346.6    352.8   0.003346274   0.03886   0.19671  -0.00158   0.01289
  17   29801.9    335.5   0.054361358   0.60051   0.75911   0.09997   0.11947
  18   30167.7    331.5   0.003135649   0.03422   0.07308   0.09437  -0.14133
  19   30283.1    330.2   0.004904058   0.05331  -0.04638   0.04267   0.22213
  20   30387.1    329.1   0.001392025   0.01508  -0.08350   0.08935   0.01119
  21   30672.5    326.0   0.005709703   0.06128   0.02037  -0.16620  -0.18234
  22   30846.4    324.2   0.003532356   0.03770   0.00014  -0.06299   0.18366
  23   31358.5    318.9   0.052168601   0.54768  -0.73435  -0.05319  -0.07469
  24   32396.1    308.7   0.000757759   0.00770  -0.04583   0.04628  -0.05881
  25   32866.9    304.3   0.000099944   0.00100  -0.00306  -0.02728  -0.01573
  26   18185.0    549.9   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  27   18426.0    542.7   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  28   18553.5    539.0   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  29   18860.8    530.2   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  30   20784.7    481.1   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  31   20951.1    477.3   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  32   21117.5    473.5   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  33   21251.4    470.6   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  34   25098.6    398.4   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  35   25150.7    397.6   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  36   25201.6    396.8   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  37   25343.5    394.6   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  38   26831.7    372.7   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  39   26943.1    371.2   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  40   27071.4    369.4   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  41   27312.2    366.1   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  42   27774.2    360.0   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  43   27988.6    357.3   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  44   28171.9    355.0   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  45   28326.5    353.0   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  46   28961.3    345.3   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  47   28989.9    344.9   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  48   29081.4    343.9   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  49   29189.0    342.6   spin forbidden (mult=3)
  50   29631.7    337.5   spin forbidden (mult=3)

Do oscillator strengths matter? I mean, should I consider State 3, as produced by ORCA, as the actual first excited state? It has fine fosc value whereas it is negligible for State 1 and State 2
The experimental spectrum is provided below:

Thanks for advice,

Your question was edited due to this rule: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5 .

Hi @farmaceut , in your edit you've accidentally removed the table headings which will make the question difficult to read for others in the future. You may want to add these back?

Oscillator strengths definitely do matter!
And they're often quite reliable, at least qualitatively, but that doesn't mean you should ignore states with low oscillator strength. You're right that state 2 has a very low f and might be hard to observe, but state 1 is only 0.7% as intense as state 3. This sort of difference should be observable in an experiment I would think.
However...
Excited states are normally over-estimated by TD-DFT
Meaning the computationally derived excited state energies are normally higher in energy (more blue, shorter wavelength) than the experimentally observed spectrum. This is by no means guaranteed, but is commonly the case because real-world stabilising effects are not accounted for in the calculation (such as stabilisation by the solvent). If the excited states have a high degree of charge-transfer character and the experiment was conducted in a polar solvent, this stabilisation can be quite significant.
However, your experimental lambda max is 445 nm, while your highest energy excited state is only 466 nm. It's only a guess, but I would imagine you've actually missed the excited state responsible for the experimental absorption peak. Try repeating the calculation with more states (10 or 20 perhaps, depending on what you can afford).
Also, if you have the full experimentally obtained absorption spectrum (rather than just the maximum absorption) that might help with the assignment. Perhaps you will see other, lower-energy peaks in the green region that correspond to the states you have calculated.
Update following edit
Well, looks like my prediction was wrong. I can't see any excited states in the output that look like good matches to the experimental peak at 445 nm, which is strange. Perhaps your state 3 does correspond to the experimental peak, I'm afraid without knowing more about the calculation and/or experiment it's impossible to tell.
Again, if you have the full experimental absorption spectrum we may be able to help more.
Update 2
Thanks for posting the spectrum, that helps a lot. You can see a very low intensity bump in the spectrum around ~500 nm with a long tail, this is likely arising from your S1/S2 states. The broader and more intense peak at ~450 nm seems like a good fit for state 3. The two narrow, high-energy peaks at ~ 325 and 340 nm look like they correspond to states 17 and 23, so I would tentatively assign them as such. You're missing the high-energy absorptions < 300nm in your calculation, you can calculate more states if you want to model these too.
I don't see any problem with assigning the peak at ~450 nm to S3 based on the data provided, which I think was your original question.


I run 25 excited states (for singlets and triplets), please take a look at the edit OP.


Only maximum absorption wavelength is provided. I include plotted experimental spectra which are accesible. Compound 3

Appreciate advice! I study photosensitising properties. Typically, it involves excitation from S0 to higher excited states, followed by the internal conversion to S1 and ISC to low lying triplets and, ultimately, phosphorescence. That’s now a question whether system obey Kasha’s rule or not ! Either way - the experimentalist recognised  445nm as a highest peak, so shouldn’t it be my reference after all?

@farmaceut that sounds very interesting, but I'm afraid I don't totally understand your question.  A reference for what? Are you now talking about calculating the potential emission (fluorescence) energy?

Sorry, ignore.I was tired and actually wonder now what I've actually meant to ask you. Thanks for explanation once again! If I find any more problems with the topic, I'm going to comment again.
